React Context.Provider returns undefined
I have a Context.Provider with a value
When I import it in the child component with useContext it returns undefined
I don't see what I'm missing here
For context here is the folder structure
src
    slider
        edit.js
        index.js
    slide
        edit.js
        index.js

build
    slider
        index.js
    slide
        index.js

index.js
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Edit from './edit';
import save from './save';
import metadata from './block.json';

/**
 * Every block starts by registering a new block type definition.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/
 */
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,

    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
} );

import React, { createContext, useRef } from 'react'
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor'

export const SlideContext = createContext()

export default function Edit() {
    const slideRefs = useRef([])

    const setSlideRef = (ref, index) => {
        slideRefs.current[index] = ref
        console.log('setSlideRef called with ref:', ref, 'and index:', index)
    }

    // some code omitted for brevity

    console.log('Rendering Slider component with context value:', { setSlideRef })

    const blockProps = useBlockProps()

    return (
        <SlideContext.Provider value={{ setSlideRef }}>
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <div className='splash-slider__wrapper'>
                    <div
                        className='splash-slider__track'
                    >
                        <InnerBlocks
                            allowedBlocks={['splash-blocks/slide']}
                            renderAppender={() => <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender />}
                            templateLock={false}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </SlideContext.Provider>
    )
}


import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor'
import { useEffect, useRef, useContext } from '@wordpress/element' // Same as React
import { SlideContext } from '../slider/edit' // Import the context from the parent block

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes, clientId }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        className: 'splash-slider__slide'
    })
    const slideRef = useRef()

    const slideContext = useContext(SlideContext)
    console.log('slideContext:', slideContext) // logs: undefined
    const { setSlideRef } = slideContext || {}

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('slideRef.current:', slideRef.current) // logs correctly
        if (setSlideRef && slideRef.current) {
            console.log('Setting slideRef with clientId:', clientId)

            setSlideRef(slideRef, clientId)
        }
    }, [setSlideRef, clientId])

    return (
        <div {...blockProps} ref={slideRef}>
            // InspectorControls and PanelBody omitted for brevity
            <InnerBlocks />
        </div>
    )
}



Where is the second component in the component tree, relative to the first one? To get the context value, the second component must be a descendant of the first (i would refer to them by name, but they're both named "Edit")

You have two export default function Edit in the code you've shown us, but it's not clear how you are using them

@NicholasTower I added the file/folder structure for context

I guess you forgot to memoize the value props in your context.

I'm not asking about the file tree, but the component tree. What component renders Edit #2? Eg, a line of code similar to <Edit attributes={/*...*/} setAttributes{/*...*/} clientId={/*...*}/>. This must be inside Edit #1 for the context to work.

@NicholasTower index.js

Also, useRef has some limits (https://fr.react.dev/reference/react/useRef#caveats)
